# Does starting age matter in Viking Conquest?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

Since Viking Conquest recently got released, I was curious if starting age did matter (like starting money etc). No one seemed to be able to answer that online. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can find suggests that starting age affects stats in the following way:

```
young: str +4, agi +4
adult: str +3, agi+3, int+3, cha+3
old: int+4, cha+4
```

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=356134613)